# What characters are automatically url-escaped by C++ Windows HttpOpenRequest()?

Tags: c++, url-encoding, wininet

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows, C++ and Win32.  I have a URL which contains spaces and other unsafe characters.  If I paste the un-escaped URL into Postman, Postman correctly escapes them and the request works.  But if I put the un-escaped URL into HttpOpenRequest(), some characters but not all are escaped as detected in the receiving system.

Original:
    https://nsw.redacted.com/ScheduledActivitys;zoneId=urn:www.dec.nsw.gov.au:school:8481;contextId=current?where=[(//ScheduledActivitys/ScheduledActivity/ActivityDate>="2017-08-11") and (//ScheduledActivitys/ScheduledActivity/ActivityDate<="2017-08-11")]

Postman:  https://nsw.redacted.com/ScheduledActivitys;zoneId=urn:www.dec.nsw.gov.au:school:8481;contextId=current?where=[(//ScheduledActivitys/ScheduledActivity/ActivityDate%3E=%222017-08-10%22)%20and%20(//ScheduledActivitys/ScheduledActivity/ActivityDate%3C=%222017-08-10%22)]

Wininet:
  https://nsw.redacted.com/ScheduledActivitys;zoneId=urn:www.dec.nsw.gov.au:school:8481;contextId=current?where=[(//ScheduledActivitys/ScheduledActivity/ActivityDate>="2017-08-11")%20and%20(//ScheduledActivitys/ScheduledActivity/ActivityDate<="2017-08-11")]

So my question is: what am I supposed to do - escape the characters myself, or rely on the Win32 library to escape them, or try to work around an incomplete implementation in the Win32 Wininet library?  Is there a danger it'll be URL-encoded twice?  And in other reading it looks like you're not  supposed to escape the "query" part of a URL (the piece after the '?') - is that advice not correct?  (And what characters are escaped and why do Microsoft escape some and not others?)

Answer (score 0):

In your example wininet URL encodes nothing but the blanks, right? That won't do, of course. You have to do the URL encoding yourself. Wininet expects a valid URL; if you don't encode the query properly it isn't valid. The good news is that URL encoding is a simple matter. Just a few lines of code.